# Which Debian-based distros gives clear easy dual boot setup w/Windows10?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, encryption

Which Debian-based distros gives clear easy dual boot setup w/Windows10?

My Windows10 is currently encrypted with BitLocker using TPM module and I'd like to also encrypt Linux with password or something else (I don't think any Linux supports TPM?)

/* I know Ubuntu but I'm looking for something lighter, and not like Ubuntu Flavor, but Mint, MX or Elementary?

Is this the feature of Calamares installer?

Answer (score 1):

with debian based distros the booting proccess usually depends on grub. While installing you can setup LVM to get partitions encrypted, if want to encrypt later can use cryptsetup from de terminal and for the automounting you will need to edit /etc/fstab and /etc/crypttab.
In the other hand dual boot is quite simple in debian based systems, I highly recommend Linux Mint according of what you want.
DO NOT forget separate /boot partition if desire full system encryption